How do implement a when a div was clicked it will expand and scroll to that div smoothly?
I have 1 parent div and 4 child div, the 4 child take all the space evenly, and when user click one of the child it expand taking all the space and the parent will be scrollable horizontally. My problem is how do I make the child move to the center of the screen when user click. Like when clicked it snap to that child and expand
Here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/jmingua/hj3nmbd7/3/

I tried the scrollintoview method but it does not work:


const items = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper");
items.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", () => {
    item.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: "smooth",
      block: "center",
      inline: "center",
    });
    item.classList.add("active");
  });
});
.container-selection {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: calc(100% - var(--l-footer-height) - 5.5rem);
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding-inline: 1rem;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.container-selection .selection {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-self: stretch;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  gap: 1rem;
  min-width: calc(25vw - 2rem);
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  transition: flex 0.3s ease;
}

.container-selection::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper.active {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  scroll-margin-block: 3rem;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-self: stretch;
}
  <div class="container-selection">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="selection glass" id="admin">
        <img src="<?= ADMIN_ICON ?>" alt="admin icon">
        <span>ADMIN</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="selection glass" id="official">
        <img src="<?= OFFICIAL_ICON ?>" alt="official icon">
        <span>OFFICIAL</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="selection glass" id="faculty">
        <img src="<?= FACULTY_ICON ?>" alt="faculty icon">
        <span>FACULTY</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="selection glass" id="nonteaching">
        <img src="<?= NONTEACHING_ICON ?>" alt="nonteaching icon">
        <span>NON-TEACHING</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




When do you remove .active?

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself  preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link.
